# Powershell, Send SMTP email with 'Mileage' field (Microsoft Exchange)

Tags: email, powershell, outlook, smtp, exchange-server

I am currently trying to send an email through powershell with a populated mileage field in order for outlook to pick up on.

The email goes through fine but I am unable to get a value through for the 'Mileage' Field.

```
$SMTPName = ''
$EmailMessage = new-object Net.Mail.MailMessage
$SMTPServer = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SMTPName)
$EmailMessage.Headers.Add("Mileage", "HB")
$EmailMessage.From = ''
$EmailMessage.To.Add('')
$EmailMessage.Subject = $sub
$EmailMessage.Body = $body
$EmailMessage.Priority = [System.Net.Mail.MailPriority]::High
$SMTPServer.Send($EmailMessage)
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "unable to get a value through"? Your code works fine in terms of sending an email with a "Mileage: HB" header. It might be stripped out by an MTA during transport of the message, or by the mail client (although unlikely)

Comment: Sorry I was unclear. I meant that using outlook and showing the 'Mileage' field shows no data. I can see it has been added to the header although under more research I have found that this 'Mileage' Field is not even sent in the header, So now I am completely stumped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mileage is a MAPI property so you will need to send the message with either Outlook or EWS  eg the following should work to send a message with that property set in EWS

```
    ## Get the Mailbox to Access from the 1st commandline argument

    $MailboxName = $args[0]

    ## Load Managed API dll  
    Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange\Web Services\1.2\Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll"  

    ## Set Exchange Version  
    $ExchangeVersion = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeVersion]::Exchange2010_SP2  

    ## Create Exchange Service Object  
    $service = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService($ExchangeVersion)  

    ## Set Credentials to use two options are availible Option1 to use explict credentials or Option 2 use the Default (logged On) credentials  

    #Credentials Option 1 using UPN for the windows Account  
    $psCred = Get-Credential  
    $creds = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($psCred.UserName.ToString(),$psCred.GetNetworkCredential().password.ToString())  
    $service.Credentials = $creds      

    #Credentials Option 2  
    #service.UseDefaultCredentials = $true  

    ## Choose to ignore any SSL Warning issues caused by Self Signed Certificates  

    ## Code From http://poshcode.org/624
    ## Create a compilation environment
    $Provider=New-Object Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider
    $Compiler=$Provider.CreateCompiler()
    $Params=New-Object System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters
    $Params.GenerateExecutable=$False
    $Params.GenerateInMemory=$True
    $Params.IncludeDebugInformation=$False
    $Params.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.DLL") | Out-Null

    $TASource=@'
      namespace Local.ToolkitExtensions.Net.CertificatePolicy{
        public class TrustAll : System.Net.ICertificatePolicy {
          public TrustAll() { 
          }
          public bool CheckValidationResult(System.Net.ServicePoint sp,
            System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate cert, 
            System.Net.WebRequest req, int problem) {
            return true;
          }
        }
      }
    '@ 
    $TAResults=$Provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource($Params,$TASource)
    $TAAssembly=$TAResults.CompiledAssembly

    ## We now create an instance of the TrustAll and attach it to the ServicePointManager
    $TrustAll=$TAAssembly.CreateInstance("Local.ToolkitExtensions.Net.CertificatePolicy.TrustAll")
    [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::CertificatePolicy=$TrustAll

    ## end code from http://poshcode.org/624

    ## Set the URL of the CAS (Client Access Server) to use two options are availbe to use Autodiscover to find the CAS URL or Hardcode the CAS to use  

    #CAS URL Option 1 Autodiscover  
    $service.AutodiscoverUrl($MailboxName,{$true})  
    "Using CAS Server : " + $Service.url   

    #CAS URL Option 2 Hardcoded  

    #$uri=[system.URI] "https://casservername/ews/exchange.asmx"  
    #$service.Url = $uri    

    ## Optional section for Exchange Impersonation  

    #$service.ImpersonatedUserId = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ImpersonatedUserId([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ConnectingIdType]::SmtpAddress, $MailboxName) 

    $EmailMessage = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EmailMessage -ArgumentList $service  
    $EmailMessage.Subject = "Message Subject"  
    #Add Recipients    
    $EmailMessage.ToRecipients.Add("user@domain.com")  
    $EmailMessage.Body = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.MessageBody  
    $EmailMessage.Body.BodyType = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.BodyType]::HTML  
    $EmailMessage.Body.Text = "Body" 
    $Mileage = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExtendedPropertyDefinition([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.DefaultExtendedPropertySet]::Common,34100,[Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.MapiPropertyType]::String);
    $EmailMessage.SetExtendedProperty($Mileage,"HB")
    $EmailMessage.SendAndSaveCopy()  enter code here
```

Comment: Very Comprehensive answer, Thank you!